# SharePoint IF(OR formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, power-platform

I have a column (Country) in Sharepoint with the name of countries. I want to create another calculated column that separates the Countries by regions as follows:

Latin American countries received the value "LAA"
Countries in North America received the value "NAA"
Countries in Europe received the "EMEA" value
And countries in Asia received the value "APAC"

I created the following formula for this:

=IF(OR([Country]="Argentina",[Country]="Bolivia",[Country]="Brazil",[Country]="Chile",[Country]="Colombia",[Country]="Costa Rica",[Country]="Cuba",[Country]="Dominican Republic",[Country]="Ecuador",[Country]="El Salvador",[Country]="Guatemala",[Country]="Haiti",[Country]="Honduras",[Country]="Jamaica",[Country]="Mexico",[Country]="Nicaragua",[Country]="Panama",[Country]="Paraguay",[Country]="Peru",[Country]="Puerto Rico",[Country]="Trinidad and Tobago",[Country]="Uruguay",[Country]="Venezuela"),"LAA",IF(OR([Country]="Canada",[Country]="United States"),"NAA",IF(OR([Country]="Austria",[Country]="Belgium",[Country]="Bulgaria",[Country]="Croatia",[Country]="Cyprus",[Country]="Czech Republic",[Country]="Denmark",[Country]="Estonia",[Country]="Finland",[Country]="France",[Country]="Germany",[Country]="Greece",[Country]="Hungary",[Country]="Iceland",[Country]="Ireland",[Country]="Italy",[Country]="Latvia",[Country]="Liechtenstein",[Country]="Lithuania",[Country]="Luxembourg",[Country]="Malta",[Country]="Monaco",[Country]="Netherlands",[Country]="Norway",[Country]="Poland",[Country]="Portugal",[Country]="Romania",[Country]="Slovakia",[Country]="Slovenia",[Country]="Spain",[Country]="Sweden",[Country]="Switzerland",[Country]="United Kingdom"),"EMEA",IF(OR([Country]="Afghanistan",[Country]="Bangladesh",[Country]="Bhutan",[Country]="Brunei",[Country]="Cambodia",[Country]="China",[Country]="India",[Country]="Indonesia",[Country]="Japan",[Country]="Kazakhstan",[Country]="Kyrgyzstan",[Country]="Laos",[Country]="Malaysia",[Country]="Maldives",[Country]="Mongolia",[Country]="Myanmar",[Country]="Nepal",[Country]="North Korea",[Country]="Pakistan",[Country]="Philippines",[Country]="Singapore",[Country]="South Korea",[Country]="Sri Lanka",[Country]="Taiwan",[Country]="Tajikistan",[Country]="Thailand",[Country]="Turkmenistan",[Country]="Uzbekistan",[Country]="Vietnam"),"APAC","Region undefined")

However, this formula has a syntax error. Can you help me to correct it please?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that were wrong with the formula you posted:

- Missing closing brackets
- Too many `OR` conditions. An `OR` only accepts a maximum of 30 conditions. This is the reason you will see 2 `EMEAS` and `APAC` `IF` conditions below. Refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) for more info

Another tip I would give when handling huge nested `IF` code will be to indent them in an editor which will make it much easier to read and also spot errors. Also to debug, reduce the number of `OR` conditions first and slowly work your way up.

```
 =IF(OR([Country]="Argentina",[Country]="Bolivia",[Country]="Brazil",[Country]="Chile",[Country]="Colombia",[Country]="Costa Rica",[Country]="Cuba",[Country]="Dominican Republic",[Country]="Ecuador",[Country]="El Salvador",[Country]="Guatemala",[Country]="Haiti",[Country]="Honduras",[Country]="Jamaica",[Country]="Mexico",[Country]="Nicaragua",[Country]="Panama",[Country]="Paraguay",[Country]="Peru",[Country]="Puerto Rico",[Country]="Trinidad and Tobago",[Country]="Uruguay",[Country]="Venezuela")
    , "LAA"
    , IF(OR([Country]="Canada",[Country]="United States")
        ,"NAA"
        ,IF(OR([Country]="Austria",[Country]="Belgium",[Country]="Bulgaria",[Country]="Croatia",[Country]="Cyprus",[Country]="Czech Republic",[Country]="Denmark",[Country]="Estonia",[Country]="Finland",[Country]="France",[Country]="Germany",[Country]="Greece",[Country]="Hungary",[Country]="Iceland",[Country]="Ireland",[Country]="Italy",[Country]="Latvia",[Country]="Liechtenstein",[Country]="Lithuania",[Country]="Luxembourg",[Country]="Malta",[Country]="Monaco",[Country]="Netherlands",[Country]="Norway",[Country]="Poland",[Country]="Portugal",[Country]="Romania",[Country]="Slovakia",[Country]="Slovenia",[Country]="Spain")
            , "EMEA"
            , IF(OR([Country]="Sweden",[Country]="Switzerland",[Country]="United Kingdom")
                , "EMEA"
                , IF(OR([Country]="Afghanistan",[Country]="Bangladesh",[Country]="Bhutan",[Country]="Brunei",[Country]="Cambodia",[Country]="China",[Country]="India",[Country]="Indonesia",[Country]="Japan",[Country]="Kazakhstan",[Country]="Kyrgyzstan",[Country]="Laos",[Country]="Malaysia",[Country]="Maldives",[Country]="Mongolia",[Country]="Myanmar",[Country]="Nepal")
                    , "APAC"
                    , IF(OR([Country]="North Korea",[Country]="Pakistan",[Country]="Philippines",[Country]="Singapore",[Country]="South Korea",[Country]="Sri Lanka",[Country]="Taiwan",[Country]="Tajikistan",[Country]="Thailand",[Country]="Turkmenistan",[Country]="Uzbekistan",[Country]="Vietnam")
                        , "APAC"
                        , "Region Undefined"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I tried the way you suggested but it still throws a syntax error.
Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @FelipeAndré I revised my answer. Please try again. If it works, please also help Accept this as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Can you also accept the answer (tick), so it can help others with similar problems? Thanks